# Email notification when Event grid fails in event delivery against its subscriber

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I am using Azure function to subscribe events from event grid topic.

Due to some failure If my Azure function stopped to work then Azure event delivery fails.

How to get emails notification when this delivery fails.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Event Grid support [dead-lettering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry#dead-letter-events). Once all [retries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry#retry-schedule-and-duration) have been exhausted, when dead-lettering is configure configured, failed events will be stored in Storage account as blobs. At that point, you're free to chose what mechanism to use to send your email notification. One option is to use [Azure Function with Storage Blob trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function) with [SendGrid email binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid).

Comment: Sir, I am using retry policy setting but don't want to send all failed event into blob storage.
I am looking  to get email notification whenever delivery fails. don't want to wait for blob storage new entities.

Comment: Wait is a strong word. You'll get notified withing a second that there was blob created. Aside from dead-lettering and responding to that, there's not much I know that's available for Event Grid as of now.